# <adlcp:prerequisites> element in SCORM 1.2

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I want to convert the manifest file from SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004 3rd edition. What is the corresponding element for SCORM 1.2 `<adlcp:prerequisites>` element in SCORM 2004 3rd edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the precondition sequencing rules in the sequencing and navigation book.

To emulate a prerequisite, you will first want to define a global objective on the primary objective of the SCO that is the prereq. Make sure that it writes satisfied status to the global.

Then, on the activity that you wish to have disabled, create a local objective that reads from the global objective for the prereq activity. Then create a precondition sequencing rule that says "if the local objective is not satisfied or has an unknown status, then disabled". That will disable the current activity until the prerequisite is satisfied.

See the ["Forced Sequential" SCORM sample course](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/#forcedsequencial) for an example manifest that implements prerequisites.